# Is there an infinite amount of numbers that cannot be written as a sum of two or more consecutive numbers?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Suppose that, $$A=\{\textrm{positive integers that can be written as a sum of}\\  \textrm{two or more positive consecutive integers}\}$$

Is there an infinite number of elements that doesnot belong to the set $A$ ?

Comment: Hint: what are $n+(n+1)$ and $(n-1)+n+(n-1)$? What numbers can't be written in one of these forms for $n>0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: If $n$ is the sum of the $k$ consecutive positive integers $a,a+1,\dots,a+k-1$, then $n=(k/2)(2a+k-1)$. This is a probably familiar fact (sum of an arithmetic progression).

Show that if $n$ is a power of $2$, then $n$ cannot be expressed as $(k/2)(2a+k-1)$, where $k\gt 1$.

Comment: Is the last statement an if-and-only-if statement?

Comment: @shardulc: Yes it is. Odd numbers $\gt 1$ are easily representable. And from a representation of $q$ we can find a representation of $2q$.

Comment: How can we say that "if $n$ is a power of $2$, then $n$ cannot be expressed as $(k/2)(2a+k-1)$" ?

Comment: I had left out the finish to leave something for you to do; But here goes. If $n$  is a power of $2$. and of the form above, then $k$ must be a power of $2$. in particular, since $k\ge 2$, it must be **even**. But then $2a+k-1$ is odd, and greater than $1$. This is impossible, since a power of $2$ cannot have an odd divisor $\gt 2$.